# Is there a performance difference SQL vs LINQ

Tags: azure-cosmosdb

We're building an application with DocumentDb backend that will get lots of hits and its reponsiveness is absolutely paramount.

I wanted to see if there was a "preferred" approach from a performance stand point in querying DocumentDb. Should we use SQL for our queries or LINQ?

Comment: Either approach will have its own quirks, issues, performance considerations, etc...  This question might be a better fit on Programmers SE.

Comment: @ChrisO: There doesn't appear to be enough detail in the question to make it a good Programmers SE candidate.

Comment: @ChrisO this question is a _very_ poor fit for Programmers - it would be quickly voted down and closed over there, see [Gorilla vs. Shark](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2011/08/gorilla-vs-shark/) Recommended reading: **[What goes on Programmers.SE? A guide for Stack Overflow](http://meta.programmers.stackexchange.com/q/7182/31260)**

Comment: Thanks @RobertHarvey and gnat for clarifying.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Theoretically, there shouldn't be a noticable difference in regards to responsiveness.

LINQ is a simply a fluent wrapper API, that which given a LINQ expression generates a SQL expression. You can view the generated SQL expression by applying toString() to the end of the LINQ expression. The performance hit on converting a LINQ expression to SQL is negligible compared the time it takes to perform I/O.

In practice, the translation from a LINQ expression may result in a sub-optimal SQL expression when dealing with corner cases. For those corner cases, working directly with SQL would be preferred.

Comment: I assume that you're talking about Linq within the context of Entity Framework.  Linq itself has mostly to do with strongly-typed collections of data, not SQL per se.  Note that DocumentDB deals mostly with JSON data: see https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/documentdb-sql-query/  There's no mention of Linq in that article.

Comment: I'm talking in the context of the DocumentDB LINQ Provider, since the question is regarding DocumentDB.